# Select attribute which is not current_user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a messaging system in Rails, and in order to display conversation partners, I get their ID from the messages that current_user is included in:

```
Message.where("to_id = ? or user_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

However, as I need **only** the other user's id from that query, I need to select it, and I would like to choose either `:to_id` or `:user_id` whichever **is not** equal to `current_user.id`

Something like:

```
Message.where("to_id = ? or user_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id).select(:to_id, :user_id unless current_user.id)
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is the Messages table simplified:

```
  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "to_id" -> User to whom the message was forwarded to
    t.integer  "user_id" -> User who wrote the message
  end
```

Comment: are you just trying to get an Array of IDs, or do you need to know if they are from the :to_id, and :user_id fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your just trying to get the IDs:

```
 Message.where("to_id = ? or user_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id).
      map { |m|
         m.user_id == current_user.id ? m.to_id : m.user_id
      }
```

this will give you and Array like

```
# => [3771, 3611, 3749, 3638, 3697, 3786]
```

Comment: Yes, only needed to have the id's without ownership. That worked, thank you a ton!